# How to access token.ent_type from Doc object in nlp.pipe()?

Tags: nlp, pipe, spacy

I am working with `spacy` and would like to know that if there is any way to access the `token.ent_type` attribute from a `Doc` object that is returned from the `nlp.pipe()` function. In `Doc` object, there is a attribute called `ents`, but it doesn't have the `ent_type` attribute. How can I access the `ent_type` attribute using a Doc object.

Comment: The spaCy docs are very clear on this: `ent_type` is part of the Token api, not Doc. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to get the ent_type attribute using the Doc object?

Comment: You can get a token from the Doc and check the token `ent_type`, ex: `doc[0].ent_type_`. Is that what you want?